# Data from preview pan in C#

Tags: c#, file, properties

As the screenshot below, 
i would like to know if i can get the "[5]:V6.04.04" given by the windows preview pan,
into a c# string ?

Advanced data in windows preview pan

[image]

Comment: can you post the code which you have tried ?

Comment: i've tryied to use FileInfo class, but i only got basic properties informations...

Comment: FileInfo oFileInfo = new FileInfo(file);
 Console.WriteLine(oFileInfo.Name);